# When do I tech?

Tags: starcraft-2

I play Zerg in the HotS beta mainly, and every time I die it's because of
plain stupid reasons, I have great economy, 3+ more bases then my opponent, good saturation,
etc.  I usually like to keep denying their bases, I'm supposed to try to think about denying the third at least. My question is *when* am I supposed to tech? When do I get other units, such as Ultras or Infestors?

Question: Can someone give me a chart for tech timings? ty :)

Comment: "I should have won" is not a valid reason to ask a question here. There is no definitive chart with timings, you need to develop your own style. If you have a specific build that fails in a specific way, we can help. If you are just entitled to win while playing bad - sorry, that can't be helped.

Answer (score 2):

It sound as if your map control and macro has a solid foundation, and thats great. Your problem seems to be that your getting caught up in your macro and forgetting you still have to destroy your opponent. Simply put, **Tech up as soon as you can afford to do so**. If your games are going as you've described, then you should be sittin on at least 2k minerals and half as much gas at any given time. Money in the bank does you NO GOOD. Spend that cash, as soon as it's available to continue progressing up the tech tree as fast as you can manage. Your problem, as you have described it, isn't about not knowing when to tech, it sounds more like your just flat out not doing it.